# know which functions are called by a cocoa application

Tags: cocoa, function

I am trying to know which functions are used by another application (which I do not have the source code)
Which tool can provide me this information?

I tried with class-dump but it does not seem to be the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

The nearest you can get is `nm`, which will list all the symbols in an executable. Some of those symbols will be the names of the functions it uses.